# Group by on join and calculate max of groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables as described below:

All three tables and output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlmiF.png)

posts [post table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ2n7.png)

post_comments [posts comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwIk4.png)

comments [comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yejl.png)

Now I want to fetch the posts that have highest liked comments and the status of that comment should be active in Postgres.

OUTPUT:

posts [resultant posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WtFg.png)

NOTE: Since for post 1, the highest liked comment is inactive.

I've tried something like this:

```
select "posts".*
from "posts" 
inner join (select id, max(likes) l from comments innner join post_comments on comments.id = post_comments.alert_id and post_comments.post_id = posts.id) a on posts.id = a.cid ...
```

This is not complete but I'm unable to do this.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, you can get the active comment with the most likes for each post using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (pc.post_id) pc.*
from post_comments pc join
     comments c
     on pc.comment_id = c.id
where c.status = 'active'
order by pc.post_id, c.likes desc;
```

I think this is quite related to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT posts.*, MAX(likes) l
FROM posts
  JOIN post_comments ON post_id = posts.id
  LEFT JOIN comments ON comment_id = comments.id
GROUP BY posts.id
```